# How can a user be saved without a created_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

This is a weird question... The context is that somehow, my program keeps creating weird arbitrary blank users with no information. I'm trying to debug it because it's certainly annoying but I don't want it to have some potentially other problems.

I'd like to debug it by figuring out when these random blank users were created and then looking at the logs with that time stamp. Unfortunately the user looks like this:

```
#<User id: 175, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, stripe_customer_id: nil, stripe_card_id: nil, invite_code: nil, invited_by: nil, profile_pic: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, full_name: nil>
```

I didn't realize it was possible to have this happen (creation without `created_at`), so am curious to see what could lead to this, and maybe that will help the debugging.

FYI I have tried to just look at my log over a long time period but the weird thing is I definitely do NOT see the actual `create` action being called so many times. I even have a `puts` statement right after the `create` just to catch this and it has only been logged twice (the appropriate amount). FWIW I'm using Devise.

Thanks

Comment: You could try disallowing `nil` for the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns in the database itself (this should normally be the case anyway). Then when the problem code tries to write a blank record you'll get an error right as problem occurs.

Comment: oh that's a good idea. that would throw an exception right?

Comment: If you share code and the piece of log chance to get answered increased a lot

Comment: @Anatoly, I would like to, but in this case, as I said there's no log when the User is created, so literally I'd be showing ALL of my code and ALL of my logs.